# How to make QToolButton go beyond the edge of QToolbar?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtoolbar

How can I make the button go beyond the edge of [QToolbar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html)?

[image]

Below is the code as I create the toolbar:

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0)

private:
    QToolBar* _toolBar;
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
   _toolBar = new QToolBar;
   QAction *actionAdd = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/add.png"), "", this);
   _toolBar->addAction(actionAdd);

    addToolBar(Qt::ToolBarArea::TopToolBarArea, _toolBar);

}
```

style.qss

```
QToolBar {
    background: #018ac4;
    height: 150px;

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post some code about how you are doing the things.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Most probably it is something about styling. I could not make this appear in my project using given a code. Do you have this project in github or other? If you want I can take a look at.

Comment: I don't think you can compose your tool bar in that way, i.e. draw child widget beyond the borders of its parent. The only way is making the button independent and overlay it on the tool bar.

Comment: [qtitanribbon](http://www.devmachines.com/qtitanribbon-overview.html) should be a good reference for make a professional appreance

Comment: @Bobur. It is just simple application (https://github.com/enshirokov/toolbar)

Comment: I tried your code and didn't see anything like your picture. Everything is just as expected. I don't know how you got that window.

Comment: @Bobur I drew a picture in the editor.
I want to make a custom toolbar that it looks like in the picture.

Comment: Ohh sorry. I totally misunderstood the question. Sorry ((

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QWidget Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301819/qwidget-overflow)

Comment: Could you please mention the Qt version, because the code works well at Qt 5.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said before, it is not possible to solve this correctly using QtWidgets.
However I see two options to visually create that effect:

1. Take the button out of the tool bar and add it to the main window instead, but do not add it to a layout. Usually i would say reposition it on resize events, but since it is in the top left, you might as well just call `setGeometry()` once on startup and not worry about it later. You probably have to add last, or call `rise()` though.
2. Make it look like the button sticks out, while it really doesn't. Make the toolbar as large as the button, but paint the lower part of the toolbar in the brighter blue, so that it looks like it is part of the widget below it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with widgets. A `QWidget` can not paint outside of its area. See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48302076/6165833.

However, the `QToolBar` is not really the parent of the `QAction` because [`addAction(QAction *action)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#addAction) does not take the ownership. So maybe the `QMainWindow` could paint your `QAction` the way you want but AFAIK this is not doable through the public API of Qt.

What you could do is use QML (but you would need to use QML for the whole window then).